# 'N' type variable is not saving into 'NUMC' type table field

Tags: abap, opensql, sap-data-dictionary

My variable is of type N ie.,

```
COMP_ID(8) TYPE n
```

I have created a Transparent Table.
In my table, COMPLAINT_ID field is of type '`NUMC`'.

while I'm saving COMP_ID into my table's COMPLAINT_ID, it is not fetching the value.

Comment: Please provide more details and some running example of your code. What kind of table is it? Is it a transparent (databes) one or is it an internal one? Please improve your question, so that people can help you.

Comment: it's a transparent table

Comment: Working example still pending... Please paste your code where you do your `INSERT` or `UPDATE` or whatever it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use numc as domain of a data element, it will take 5 characters. You should give predefined type and define the length of the data element that you use in the table.I believe this is the problem. [image]

Comment: Still not working? Then simply give us some code so that we can see where the problem is. :)

Comment: I agree, post the code and errors if there is any, please? :)